# magento mobile menu display file

Tags: magento2

I would like to know where can I find the CSS files that display the menu in mobile view? So basically I'm looking for this file that when the view reaches 767px width the menu will collapse and will display the nav-toggle button to display the mobile menu. Can anyone point me to the exact file?